# How to convert JSON array of objects to JSON array of strings?

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

My code is given below and I am getting the following output, the output is fine but I just want to format the output in a comma separated list of locations. How to do this?

```
 var eventDetails = (from e in db.tb_Event                            
                      select new
                      {
                         e.EventID,
                         e.tb_Customer.CustomerName,
                         e.StartDate,
                         e.EndDate,
                         loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation where 
                                   l.EventID == e.EventID 
                                   select new { l.tb_Location.LocationName })
                                  .Distinct(),
                         e.Objective
                     });
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "EventID": 1,
        "CustomerName": "qwe",
        "StartDate": null,
        "EndDate": null,
        "loc": [
            {
                "LocationName": "asd"
            },
            {
                "LocationName": "zxc"
            }
        ],
        "Objective": "Floor Walkthrough"
    },
    {
        "EventID": 2,
        "CustomerName": "rtg",
        "StartDate": null,
        "EndDate": null,
        "loc": [
            {
                "LocationName": "asd"
            }
        ],
        "Objective": "RFP"
    },
    {
        "EventID": 3,
        "CustomerName": "zxc",
        "StartDate": null,
        "EndDate": null,
        "loc": [],
        "Objective": "RFI"
    }
]
```

I want loc to come as

```
[{"LocationName":"asd","zxc"}]
```

i.e. a comma seperated list of locations. How to do this?

Comment: So you want "LocationName" to be an array just like "loc", right?

Comment: try with something like: eventDetails.Select(xx=> xx.loc).ToList() .. could be ok?

Comment: @VítorMartins Yes

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Your solution is not working

Comment: with SelecMany?

Comment: I can provide the solution in javascript. It will be useful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try first to group locations and than take all group ids:

```
 loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation 
        where l.EventID == e.EventID 
        group  l.tb_Location.LocationName by l.tb_Location.LocationName
        select new { g.Key})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to accomplish this by making a little change in your code as below:

```
var eventDetails = (from e in db.tb_Event
                                select new
                                {
                                    e.EventID,
                                    e.tb_Customer.CustomerName,
                                    e.StartDate,
                                    e.EndDate,
                                    loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation where 
                                                l.EventID == e.EventID 
                                                select new { l.tb_Location.LocationName })
                                                .Distinct().ToArray().CombineWith(","),
                                    e.Objective
                                });
```

`CombineWith` is an extension method just to keep the code readable:

```
private static string CombineWith (this string[] locationNames,string delimiter )
{
  return string.Join(delimiter,locationNames);   
}
```

Just for a note:

`[{"LocationName":"asd","zxc"}]`  is not a valid jason. You may want something like : `[{"LocationName":"asd,zxc"}]`

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple method that creates a JArray from a collection of entities.

*Note: Data is the column that stores raw json for the entity*

Take a look:

```
 private string RawJsonFrom(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
 {
        JArray array = new JArray();
        foreach (vare in entities)            
            array.Add(JObject.Parse(e.Data));            

        return array.ToString();
 }
```